# Weird behaviour of custom UIViews when touched

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uiscrollview, touchesmoved

In a what would be [a (yet another) word game for iOS](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/tree/master/Scroll) I have a scroll view holding an image view with game board.

And underneath I have draggable custom views representing letter tiles.

For the scroll view I've added a double tap gesture recognizer for toggling its `zoomScale` (between 50% and 100% image width):

[image: app screenshot]

This works well, but I had to disable Autolayout (because otherwise scroll view's `contentOffset` would jump to `{0,0}` when I dragged the tiles).

So I had to add the following code to [ViewController.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/Scroll/Scroll/ViewController.m) to adjust scroll view's frame after device rotation:

```
- (void) adjustSubViews
{
    _scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0,
                                   0,
                                   self.view.bounds.size.width,
                                   self.view.bounds.size.height - kHeight - 2 * kPadding);
}
```

this seems to work too - but my problem is that **after first device rotation to landscape and back** "something breaks" and **the tiles are suddenly draggable by touching underneath them**:

[image: app screenshot]

Why does it happen please?

Below is an Xcode screenshot (here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iR0oi.png)) showing the scroll view properties:

[image: Xcode screenshot]

**UPDATE:** I've added size logging to the [Tile.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/Scroll/Scroll/Tile.m):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    NSLog(@"%s %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, NSStringFromCGSize(self.frame.size));

    [_smallImage setHidden:YES];
    [_smallLetter setHidden:YES];
    [_smallValue setHidden:YES];

    [_bigImage setHidden:NO];
    [_bigLetter setHidden:NO];
    [_bigValue setHidden:NO];

    [self.superview bringSubviewToFront:self];
}
```

and while initially it logs the expected tile size of 45x45 (set by me in `Tile.xib`):

```
-[Tile touchesBegan:withEvent:] {45, 45}
```

After I rotate the device to landscape and back to portrait I suddenly get the height of 160:

```
-[Tile touchesBegan:withEvent:] {45, 160}
```

Comment: I would move your calls to `adjustSubViews` and `adjustZoom` out of `viewDidLoad` and `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`, and just put them both in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` - this will get called on device rotation and after `viewDidLoad`.  You may want to update the frames of your `Tile` objects here too instead of setting those in `viewDidLoad`.  I'm not sure if this will fix your problem, but it may help isolate the issue.

Comment: I have not read the code on GitHub. How do you move your tiles?

Comment: With `touchesMoved`: https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/Scroll/Scroll/Tile.m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tile becomes draggable blow its image because the view containing the tile is auto-resized by it's superview (controller's view) that changes its frame during rotation.

[image]

This behaviour can be easily avoided by setting autoresizing mask of the tile view to `UIViewAutoresizingNone` (by deselecting all springs and struts in Interface Builder).

[image]

Note the tools to debug problems with view sizing like this one:

1. LLDB command `po viewVariableOrAddress` (calls `description` method of its parameter and prints the result).
2. [-[UIView recursiveDescription]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2239/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010638-CH1-SUBSECTION34) called from LLDB by the following command: `po [viewVariableOrAddress recursiveDescription]`. Note that his method is private and must not be called in production code (the app will be rejected otherwise).
3. [Reveal](http://revealapp.com) — in a natural GUI, represents the same information that you can get at runtime in debugger console.

Comment: Thank you, I was wrongly thinking that by disabling Autolayout I had disabled Autoresizing too... Please take a look at my other (bountied) question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310311/adding-custom-uiviews-to-a-uiscrollview-how-to-calculate-position-size-and-ha