# Adding custom UIViews to a UIScrollview - how to calculate position, size and handle zoom?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

As an iOS newbie I'm trying to develop [a (yet another) word game](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/tree/master/DragScroll).

I have a `UIScrollView` holding an `UIImageView` with the board image.

The `UIScrollView` can be zoomed by double tap and pinch gestures:

[image: app screenshot]

Underneath the `UIScrollView` I have 7 draggable `UIView`s representing letter tiles.

The implementation in [Tile.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/DragScroll/DragScroll/Tile.m) handles dragging with `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved` and posts a notification in `touchesEnded`.

The single view controller [ViewController.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/DragScroll/DragScroll/ViewController.m) observes this notification and adds/removes the tile to/from the `UIScrollView` by the following code:

```
- (void) handleTileMoved:(NSNotification*)notification {
    Tile* tile = (Tile*)notification.object;

    if (tile.superview != _scrollView && 
        CGRectIntersectsRect(tile.frame, _scrollView.frame)) {

        [tile removeFromSuperview];
        [_scrollView addSubview:tile];
        tile.frame = CGRectMake(tile.frame.origin.x + _scrollView.contentOffset.x,
                                tile.frame.origin.y + _scrollView.contentOffset.y,
                                kTileWidth * _scrollView.zoomScale,
                                kTileScale * _scrollView.zoomScale);

    } else if (tile.superview == _scrollView &&
               !CGRectIntersectsRect(tile.frame, _scrollView.frame)) {

        [tile removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view addSubview:tile];
        [self adjustFrames];
    }
}
```

This kind of works, but I have 2 problems -

[image: app screenshot]

**Problem 1:** How to calculate the position and size of the letter tile, when I am adding it to the scroll view?

Are there any comfortable functions provided by iOS for that purpose or do I have to calculate those values manually (as shown in my code above)?

**Problem 2:** When I zoom the image view (the game board), then the letter pieces placed on it don't zoom. Probably because of this method?

```
- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView*)scrollView
{
    return _imageView;
}
```

How to fix this problem? I can't return several objects by the above method

**UPDATE:**

I have [branched my app on GitHub](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/tree/Insert_contentView_between_scrollView_and_imageView/DragScroll) and inserted a `contentView` between the `scrollView` and `imageView` (here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZifR.png)):

[image: Xcode screenshot]

Zooming the image and the tiles works then, but I can't scroll anymore.

I've printed out the `contentSize` and it seem to be okay with 1000x1000:

```
-[ViewController viewDidLoad]: image {1000, 1000}
-[ViewController viewDidLayoutSubviews] contentOffset={0, 0} contentSize={1000, 1000}
tile: N 9 {2, 433} {45, 45}
tile: V 1 {47, 433} {45, 45}
tile: L 9 {92, 433} {45, 45}
tile: R 4 {137, 433} {45, 45}
tile: B 7 {182, 433} {45, 45}
tile: B 8 {227, 433} {45, 45}
tile: M 5 {272, 433} {45, 45}
-[ViewController adjustZoom]: scrollView origin={0, 0} size={320, 431} minScale=0.320000 zoomScale=0.640000 maxScale=0.640000
-[ViewController adjustZoom]: imageView origin={0, 0} size={1000, 1000}
-[ViewController adjustZoom]: contentView origin={0, 0} size={640, 640}
```

I've tried changing `_scrollView.canCancelContentTouches` and `_scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`.

Also I've tried changing the interactivity checkbox of the `UIImageView` in Interface Builder, but it hasn't helped.

I couldn't figure out the problem by using Reveal app either (here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9a3n.png)):

[image: Reveal app]

Comment: Why didn't you use a UICollectionView ? this would have made your life a lot easier.

Comment: I've found on the web and tried an UICollectionView example and the dragging of the elements wasn't smooth - sometimes you had to swipe with fingers several times. From the other word game apps I see that tile dragging can be implemented to be smooth. Also, using UICollectionView to hold the tiles isn't really related to my actual question.

Comment: The collectionView would manage the size of the cells for you and the scrollView would hold the collection view - this way you wouldnt need to work out any sizes and just have to update the data source on the collectionView.

Comment: No, I can't put the collectionView into the scrollView, because the (unplayed) tiles should always be visible at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Are you trying to snap letter tile to a cell ?

Comment: Not yet, just trying to make the tiles scroll and zoom with the board

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem 2: Use your new `contentView` as superview for the board and the pieces. That way the position and the size of the pieces in the board coordinates will be independent of the zoom and pan applied to the `contentView`.

Problem 1: There is no longer problem 1!

Comment: Actually I still have problems, even after adding the `contentView` suggested by you. I have published another question about it here at StackOverflow and will offer a bounty of 500 on it soon: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22440327/draggable-uiview-stops-posting-touchesbegan-after-being-added-to-uiscrollview

Answer (score 2):

for the problem 1:

there is two property of `UIScrollView`

```
 UIScrollView* sc = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
 CGPoint pt = sc.contentOffset;
 CGFloat scale = sc.zoomScale;
```

and for the second problem I recommend scaling the letterImage while dragging and when it comes to placing on board place it with original size scrollview will show it good