# Draggable UIView stops posting touchesBegan after being added to UIScrollView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, touchesbegan

In Xcode 5.1 I have created [a simple test app](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/tree/master/ScrollContent) for iPhone:

[image: app screenshot]

The structure is: `scrollView -> contentView -> imageView -> image 1000 x 1000` on the top.

And on the bottom of the single view app I have seven draggable custom `UIView`s.

The dragging is implemented in [Tile.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/ScrollContent/ScrollContent/Tile.m) with `touchesXXXX` methods.

**My problem is:** once I add a draggable tile to the `contentView` in my [ViewController.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/ScrollContent/ScrollContent/ViewController.m) file - I can not drag it anymore:

```
- (void) handleTileMoved:(NSNotification*)notification {
    Tile* tile = (Tile*)notification.object;
    //return;

    if (tile.superview != _scrollView && CGRectIntersectsRect(tile.frame, _scrollView.frame)) {
        [tile removeFromSuperview];
        [_contentView addSubview:tile];
        [_contentView bringSubviewToFront:tile];
    }
}
```

The `touchesBegan` isn't called for the `Tile` anymore as if the `scrollView` would mask that event.

[I've searched around](http://bynomial.com/blog/?p=74) and there was a suggestion to extend the `UIScrollView` class with the following method (in my custom [GameBoard.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/ScrollContent/ScrollContent/GameBoard.m)):

```
- (UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UIView* result = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];

    NSLog(@"%s: %hhd", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,
          [result.superview isKindOfClass:[Tile class]]);

    self.scrollEnabled = ![result.superview isKindOfClass:[Tile class]];
    return result;
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't help and prints `0` in debugger.

Comment: Just to update, UIScrollView don't respond to touch events... I will check your code...

Comment: Why do you remove it from the superview on move? Why not just move it in the hierarchy it already is, and when the users lets go, calculate the position where it should fall and only then place it?

Comment: A scroll view can certainly contain a draggable view, as is proved by this example code of mine (which you can download and try on your own machine): https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch07p383dragInScrollView/ch20p688dragInScrollView/ViewController.m

Comment: And see the discussion of that project in this section of my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch20.html#_scroll_view_touches - Basically I'd say just start with what I'm doing (which works) and then adapt it. You should be using gesture recognizers anyway, not direct touches events.

Comment: @Leo Natan: That is what I do: when "the user lets go" in `touchesEnded` (Tile.m), I post a notification. The ViewController.m "catches" this notification and: 1) removes the tiles from super view 2) adds the tile to the scroll view. This works, but then I can't to the reverse - drag the tile back (from scroll view to the bottom of the super view).

Comment: @matt I know that this is possible (having draggable tiles in a scroll view) - because I see this behaviour working fine in the popular word games "Lexulous" and "Words with Friends". I just can't figure out the code. And I can't use gesture recognizers, because I need to display shadow underneath the tile in `touchesBegan`. (And I read your book at O'Reilly Safari, thanks for writing it).

Comment: @AlexanderFarber I found the problem. Your content view has user interactions enabled = off. After turning it on, I can drag tiles. I see now why it's off. I will give you a solution in a minute

Comment: @AlexanderFarber Aaand done. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is, partly, because user interactions are disabled on the content view. However, enabling user interactions disables scrolling as the view captures all touches. So here is the solution. Enable user interactions in storyboard, but subclass the content view like so:

```
@interface LNContentView : UIView

@end

@implementation LNContentView

- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UIView* result = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];

    return result == self ? nil : result;
}

@end
```

This way, hit test passes only if the accepting view is not `self`, the content view.

Here is my commit:
https://github.com/LeoNatan/ios-newbie

Comment: Created a pull request.

Comment: +1 great, thank you. I'd like (and have to - by StackOverflow rules) to wait few days with the bounty - in case there are more answers. I will also wait with the GitHub pull request - so that the other StackOverflow users aren't confused (by the problem being not present in the code).

Comment: If you have any advice on how to set the position of the tile at the scroll view after being dragged to it... I have tried `tile.frame.origin.x + _scrollView.contentOffset.x` but it doesn't work out (also tried multiplying offset with `zoomScale`).

Comment: @AlexanderFarber You need to convert the origin point to scrollview space using `-convertPoint:toView:`. Not sure if that takes zoom scale into account. If not, you will likely need to compensate.

Comment: +1 thanks I will try it. And the other problem is how to detect when the tile is being dragged back (so that I can remove it from the game board and put at the bottom of the main view). The `!CGRectIntersectsRect(tile.frame, _scrollView.frame` doesn't work here.

Comment: Why is the bottom tray not part of the scroll view hierarchy? That way you can just bring to front, move, and then on release see if the tile is over the tray and put it there.

Comment: No, that would be uncomfortable to play. The "tray" with unplayed tiles should be always visible and thus can't be a child of the scroll view.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49984/discussion-between-leo-natan-and-alexander-farber)

Answer (score 1):

The reason Tile views don't get touches is that scroll view's pan gesture recogniser consumes the events. What you need is, attach a `UIPanGestureRecongnizer` to each of your tiles and configure them as follows:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pan:)]; // handle drag in pan:method
[tile addGestureRecognizer:pan];
UIPanGestureRecognizer *scrollPan = self.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer;
[scrollPan requireGestureRecognizerToFail:pan];
```

Here you let scroll view's pan gesture recogniser know that you only wish scrolling to happen if none of the tiles are bing dragged.

I've checked the approach — it does work indeed. Regarding your code, you'll need to handle all touches in the gesture recogniser rather than Tile view because touch events may be consumed/delayed by hit-tested view's gesture recogniser before they reach the view itself. Please refer to [UIGestureRecognizer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to learn more about the topic.

Comment: +1 thanks, Leonty, but will it still be possible to display the Tile shadow (the `bigImage` in `Tile.xib`) on user touch - if I switch from `touchesBegan` to a gesture recognizer?

Comment: @AlexanderFarber You can create a subclass of the gesture recogniser and define whatever behaviour you need in its `touchesBegan:withEvent:`. I would delegate actual handling to view controller or the Tile view itself. For now, you could just call corresponding methods on the view from your custom pan gesture recogniser.

Comment: @AlexanderFarber Oh, sorry! I haven't noticed that the real mess is in the Interface builder!  Having read your discussion with Leo above, I can say that the solution is even easier than any of the proposed.  if you set content `delaysContentTouches` on the scroll view to YES in the IB and enable user interactions on the content view, you'll get your intended behaviour (modulo the touch delivery delay).

Comment: …though you don't necessarily want the delay. So +1 to Leo's answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks as ir one of the views in the hierarchy is capturing the events.

Have a look at the section

> The Responder Chain Follows a Specific Delivery Path

Of the Apple doc's [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/multitouch_background/multitouch_background.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH5-SW9)

Edit:

Sorry I was writing from memory. This is how i resolved a similar issue in an app of myself:

I use `UITapGestureRecognizer` in the view(s) that I want to detect the touch. Implement the following delegate method of the UITapGestureRecognizer:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
```

The touches' set contains all the objects (views) that received the event.

Comment: How can I filter such events?

Comment: You can also force the views not to overlap.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how forcing the views not to overlap helps me with my problem. Also, I can't use tap gesture recognizer: I have to use `touchesBegan`, because I display an image with shadow (the `bigImage`) when user touches a Tile.